# HTML5 Progress Bar not working

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I look for similar question pertaining to my problem but couldn't fine any solution to it. I was doing an example of progress bar in HTML5, I tried IE and Chrome but the GO button isn't setting the progress bar in motion.

Here is the code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>HTML5 Progress Bar</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go();
    {
        var inc = 0;
        var doIt = setInterval(updateProgress,50);
        function updateProgress() 
        {
        inc++;
            if (inc > 100) 
            {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Done!";
            } else 
            {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = inc+ "%";
            document.getElementById("progress1").value = inc;
            }
        }
    }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <progress id = "progress1" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"> </progress> <br>
    <span id="output"> </span> <br> <br>
    <button id= "go" onclick="go()"> GO </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `function go();`  - remove the `;`

Comment: Remove ; after `function go();` and it works

Comment: Use something like Microsoft Code or Atom (both free and cross-platform) to write code. You should use a code editor that will _help you catch_ simple typos like this (integrates `jshint`, for example).

Answer (score 3):

That's because there is a semicolon `;` after your go function before your curly braces start. Try running the snippet below.

```js
function go() {
  var inc = 0;
  var doIt = setInterval(updateProgress, 50);

  function updateProgress() {
    inc++;
    if (inc > 100) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Done!";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = inc + "%";
      document.getElementById("progress1").value = inc;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<progress id="progress1" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"> </progress> <br>
<span id="output"> </span> <br> <br>
<button id="go" onclick="go()"> GO </button>
```

Comment: I knew it was  something silly I was missing or not seeing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a semicolon  `;` after `go();`, it should look like

```
function go() 
{
    var inc = 0;
    var doIt = setInterval(updateProgress,50);
    function updateProgress() 
    {
    inc++;
        if (inc > 100) 
        {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Done!";
        } else 
        {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = inc+ "%";
        document.getElementById("progress1").value = inc;
        }
    }
}
```